# Writing results of google dataflow pipeline into mulitple sinks

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I would like to write the Google dataflow pipeline results into multiple sinks.

Like, I want to write the result using TextIO into Google Cloud Storage as well write the results as a table in BigQuery. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The structure of a Cloud Dataflow pipeline is a DAG (directed acyclic graph) and it is allowed to apply multiple transforms to the same PCollection - write transforms are not an exception. You can apply multiple write transforms to the PCollection of your results, for example:

```
PCollection<Foo> results = p.apply(TextIO.Read.named("ReadFromGCS").from("gs://..."))
                         .apply(...the rest of your pipeline...);
results.apply(TextIO.Write.named("WriteToGCS").to("gs://..."));
results.apply(BigQueryIO.Write.named("WriteToBigQuery").to(...)...);
```

Comment: This will execute both transformations parllely. What if we want to do it sequentially? for ex-first write to PUBSUB and then write to SQL

Comment: For that, see the Wait.on() transform.

Comment: Wait.on() is not working actually when I write to PUBSUB it gives me PDone and I am unable to apply any other transform on it and I want to log the message in SQL which are pushed to PUBSUB.

Comment: Yeah, not all transforms are currently in shape to be waited-on. Unfortunately there is no easy workaround in these cases beyond e.g. writing your own DoFn that does both by hand.

Comment: Do you have any references for writing your own DoFn?

Comment: Custom DoFn's are present in every beam pipeline so any basic beam documentation will cover it.

Comment: This is not possible even you will find a way to write sequentially but that job will need so many resources and still not time optimized

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean.