# How to apply ParDo to a PDone object

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

My Pipeline has a follwing 2 steps.

1. To extract data from BigQuery, then translate it and store CloudStorage.
2. To extract data from the CloudStorage, then translate it and store S3.

After step1, I can get PDone object, but it does not have apply or read method.
Are there any way to attach step 2 process after step1 process?

Comment: Can you write data extracted from BigQuery directly both to S3 and CloudStorage, or is there a requirement that all data must be written to CloudStorage before writing to S3 can begin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the data extracted from BigQuery to several places at the same time. E.g. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431840/writing-results-of-google-dataflow-pipeline-into-mulitple-sinks).

Comment: I wrote the GCS first from BigQuery, then extract data from GCS and translate it and store S3. The data format for file to store S3 and GCS are different for the business purpose.